# images not staying in place, dragging with adjustment of window

Tags: html, css

When I put some images on the page they will move across the screen when I try
and adjust the size of the window on my browser. The images I'm talking about in css are coded as `.ex { position: absolute; top: 200px; right 200px; }` and they move across the screen but some do not. why does this happen and how can I prevent it.

```css
#logo {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 750px;
}

#logoleft {
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 500px;
}

#logoright {
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 420px;
}

#leftleft {
  position: absolute;
  left: 270px;
}

#rightright {
  position: absolute;
  right: 180px;
}

#bdlogo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 500px;
  left: 220px;
}

#logobelow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  right: 750px;
}

#logoprayer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 200px;
  top: 500px;
}

#gc {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  right: 20px;
}

#ib {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: 70px;
}

#fc {
  position: fixed;
  top: 350px;
  right: 1040px;
}
```

```html
<div id="rightright"><img src="data/pics/mr.png" width="140px;" height="140px;">
  <!--randomness-->
</div>
<div id="leftleft"><img src="data/pics/lr.png" width="140px;" height="140px;">
  <!--randomness-->
</div>
<div id="logoleft"><img src="data/pics/wom.png" width="145px" height="340px">
  <!--randomness-->
</div>
<div id="logo">
  <a href="index.html"><img src="data/pics/rslogo.png" width="450px;" height="170px;">
    <!--randomness-->
  </a>
</div>
<div id="logoright"><img src="data/pics/emt.png" width="245px;" height="340px;">
  <!--randomness-->
</div>
<div id="bdlogo"><img src="data/pics/bd.gif">
  <!--randomness-->
</div>
<div id="logobelow">
  <a href="index.html"><img src="data/pics/fs.png">
    <!--randomness-->
  </a>
</div>
<div id="logoprayer"><img src="data/pics/rc.gif" width="195px;" height="300px;">
  <!--randomness-->
</div>
<div id="gc"><img src="data/pics/gc.png" width="95px;" height="95px;">
  <!--randomness-->
</div>
<div id="ib"><img src="data/pics/ib.png" width="65px;" height="65px;">
  <!--randomness-->
</div>
<div id="fc"><img src="data/pics/fc.png" width="90" ; height="90" ;>
  <!--randomness-->
</div>
```

Comment: It would be better if you include your codes in the question

Comment: No problem, the codes been uploaded. I know some of the positions are fixed but I've changed them all to absolute and they still move with the widow, I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 1):

Some Of your elements are positioned fixed (`position:fixed`) which will cause the element place to stay on the same position of browser view point.

change them to `position:absolute` or `position:relative`;

```
#gc {
     position: absolute; top: 10px; right: 20px; /*consider using normal flow instead*/
}
#ib {
     position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 70px; /*consider using normal flow instead*/
}
 #fc {
     position: absolute; top: 350px; right: 1040px; /*consider using normal flow instead*/
}
```

also you should consider using `position:relative` instead of position:absolute since it just position your elements absolutely where you defined(`left:70px;` for example) and it will stay on that position no mater what(changing your browser width won't change it). you should avoid using position absolute and try to position your element with margin and padding.

some tutorial about positioning :

https://alistapart.com/article/css-positioning-101

http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningcss/p/aacss9layout.htm

use this link for better understanding of margin and padding:

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp

Comment: For some reason, even when they are all absolute they still want to follow and stay on that page, its weird because it's more the right side of the page thats having the problem vs the left.

Comment: @chrysaron press CTRL+F5. it's gonna ignore cache and reload your css again. let me know if it works.

Comment: I did and it still is dragging across the screen sadly... Idk could it be that some images are .png? or just sized to big or too small

Answer (score 0):

A jsfiddle example would be much nicer.
Absolute positioning is relative to the images parent.
The parent of these images changes so the images move.
What you could do is determine the width of the parent which has position relative.If the parent won't move the images won't move.

If you add a jsfiddle or plunker example, it will be easy to fix.